# loadrunner application is not working

Tags: loadrunner

I am using loadrunner 12 version. I am trying to record one script using loadrunner tool. But I am unable to record.

After providing the user name and password and click in sign in, It loads and it shows blank page. I have noticed that, After sign in it is going to logout page.

Could you please help any on this.

XP machine with 32 bit.
Single protocol /URL mode

Thanks
Mohammed

Answer (score 2):

1. Has it ever worked?  If not, then you likely haven't met **ALL** of the requirements for installation.  Check the installation guide and make certain you are hitting every mark, including rights in the system and disabling anti-virus
2. Try a control site.  The sample webtours website which would run locally on your machine is a great control element.  If it works here but not on your site/application then you need to look at what is different architecturally between the two which is coming into play.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to application as you are able to get credentials page and it is failing to load after submiting the userid and password.